# Search speed increase

Tags: php, mysql

I've heard that some queries like `DELETE`, or changing the structure of a table can decrease the speed of the search in a table.

First: is this true , or not?

Second: is there any way to increase it's speed again? (sth like Defragment maybe!)

Comment: first, which database engine are you using ? MyISAM or InnoDB ?

Comment: i'm using innoDB.

Comment: Well if you delete rows, ofcourse it will be faster as less rows are being searched in.

Comment: spend a nickel for a good consultant

Comment: Are you using `innodb_file_per_table` ?

Comment: "innodb_file_per_table?" what is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you doing on a regular basis `UPDATE` and/or `DELETE` statements on a table the `SELECT` speed will decrease over time because the data and indexes (if present) will be fragmented thus the search process will take more depending on the degree of fragmentation so i purpose :

- to run [OPTIMIZE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html) on the afflicted table on a regular basis (once a day should be enough) because this will defragment the data and rebuild the indexes (if present)
- add indexes (if you do not already have) on the columns most commonly used in `SELECT` statement